# Angular routing isn't displaying template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I click on my Register link it goes to the proper URL but nothing is displayed

routing code:

```
//routing module

(function () {
    'use strict'

    angular
      .module('membership.routing', ['ngRoute'])
      .config(config);

    //$routeProvider adds routing to the client
    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];


    function config($routeProvider) {
        //when() takes two arguments: a path and an options object
        $routeProvider.when('/register', {
            controller: 'RegisterController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: '/static/templates/authentication/register.html',
        }).otherwise('/');
    }
})();
```

controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('membership.authentication.controllers', [])
      //register the controller
      .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);


    RegisterController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];
    //'Authentication' is the function from the authentication service

    function RegisterController($location, $scope, Authentication) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.register = register; // allows the access of the function register()

        function register(){
            // this is calling the register method of the Authentication service
            Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password, vm.username);
        }
    }
})();
```

register.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <h1>Register</h1>

    <div class="well">
    <!-- This is the line that calls $scope.register -->
    <!-- vm is used in the router that allows us to refer to the controller -->
      <form role="form" ng-submit="vm.register()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__email">Email</label>
          <!-- ng-model responsible for storing values -->
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="register__email" ng-model="vm.email" placeholder="ex. john@notgoogle.com" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register__username" ng-model="vm.username" placeholder="ex. john" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="register__password" ng-model="vm.password" placeholder="ex. thisisnotgoogleplus" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit:

```
<div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#not-google-plus-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Not Google Plus</a>
    </div> <!-- ./navbar-header -->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="not-google-plus-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li><a href="/+{{ user.username }}">+{{ user.username }}</a></li>
          <li><a href="/+{{ user.username }}/settings">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Logout</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- /.collapse.navbar-collapse -->
  </div> <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="membership">
<head>
  <title>thinkster-django-angular-boilerplate</title>

  <base href="/" />

  {% include 'stylesheets.html' %}
</head>

<body>
  {% include 'navbar.html' %}

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 ng-view"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  {% include 'javascript.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

thinkster.js

```
angular
  .module('thinkster', [])
  .run(run);

run.$inject = ['$http'];

/**
* @name run
* @desc Update xsrf $http headers to align with Django's defaults
*/
function run($http) {
  $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
  $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';

  console.log('works')
}
```

I'm using Angular 1.7 and this tutorial https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#learning-django-and-angularjs. I'm not sure why the URL is correct but the template won't appear, the console doesn't show any error. And if I remove the HTML file from the path the console does correctly throw a 404 for it

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the page, do you see the html elements of the register.html?

Comment: right now it just keeps displaying the current page, so the navigation. But it won't leave the navigation page when I click the link

Comment: Can you include your navigation page's controller code with the template to the question as well

Comment: @Senal Just updated it

Comment: For the login page does it work? Try changing your anchor tag's href to `<a href="#/register">Register</a>`

Comment: Didn't work, I also changed disabled the hash routing as per the tutorial

Comment: Did you add `ng-view` directive in your main template

Comment: And no there's no code for the login page yet

Comment: I didn't, the tutorial doesn't mention anything of that

Comment: You need to have an `ng-view` directive which is the container of the templates of your route

Comment: @Amon I added answer with the demo, hope it will work as per your expectation and help you to identify the mistake you make.

Comment: first of all seems like you forgot to add `membership.authentication.controllers` module inside of your route module.

Comment: @DipeshParmar You mean add it as a dependency? The tutorial doesn't do that

Comment: @Amon May i know which tutorial you are following? And if possible can you share any public jsfiddle for that to look into this in detail.  because your code not helping to identify as seems main module files is missing,  so please create some fiddle.

Comment: Hey sorry I'm on my phone right now, but the link to the tutorial is on the post at the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look in to the official documentation of [$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) and [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute).

working [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3pobgcy9/) as per the code you posted in the post.

**JavaScript code :**

```
var app = angular.module('RegisterRouting', []);

app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.heading = "Home";
});

app.controller('RegisterController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.heading = "Register";

   $scope.register = register;

   function register(){
     // this is calling the register method of the Authentication service
     alert("register view call");
   }
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

**HTML code :**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <h1> {{heading}} </h1>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="register.html">
    <h1> {{heading}} </h1>

    <form role="form" ng-submit="register()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__email">Email</label>
          <!-- ng-model responsible for storing values -->
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="register__email" ng-model="vm.email" placeholder="ex. john@notgoogle.com" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register__username" ng-model="vm.username" placeholder="ex. john" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="register__password" ng-model="vm.password" placeholder="ex. thisisnotgoogleplus" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
</script>

<div> 
      <div id="navigation">  
      <a href="#/home">Home</a>
      <a href="#/register">Register</a>
      </div>

    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how exactly does the HTML reference the angular in this example? Is it by using the `id` attribute?

Comment: man nothing is happening still, all the files are being loaded. I'm about ready to give up, it's been like 2 weeks. It's showing all the files are being loaded, like is the routing just not picking up on the URL location?

Comment: @Amon Forgot that `id` thing man. It is just a demo to demonstrate the solution.

Comment: ok... Thanks for the example, but it's not working when I place it in my build. If you really want you can clone the repo and try yourself

Comment: Here's a working demo of it, posted by another answerer below https://github.com/sajeetharan/DjangoAndAngular

Comment: I figured out the issue, it looks like I was indeed missing some code from the tutorial. He split the code up into different screen shots and I thought they were different modules, no idea how I missed it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above, actually the tutorial uses ng-view in the index.html. Since you have not given the whole modules involved in the application, it is harder to identify the issues.

It's better if you go through the **[`official documentation`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)** and compare what you've done it wrong.

Also here is the **[`working Demo`](https://github.com/sajeetharan/DjangoAndAngular)** of the above tutorial i found on GitHub. Hopefully this would help and you can modify according to the way you need.

Comment: Thank you for the response, yes I found the ng-view in index.html. still not working, I'll have a look tomorrow and get back. Thanks again

Comment: Hey I'm getting the `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module` error, I got this before for my project as well and I solved it by adding a `[]` when declaring dependencies for modules

Comment: Did you not need to do that?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module thinkster due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'thinkster' is not available!` is the full error

Comment: Ok I fixed that error by adding the `[]` in thinkster.js and right now I'm still getting a `500 internal server error` on all the JS files

Comment: where exactly should it be located? I cloned the repo, should it be at the root? Also the name of your repo is DjangoAndAngular not thinkster-django-angular-boilerplate so I can't `cd` into the folder

Comment: I didn't change any of the paths

Comment: oh, I did change the name of the virtualenv because I already had one of the name you gave me. Would that cause the error?

Comment: ok I just altered the settings so now it's returning a 404 error for the files, which is a lot easier to fix, im heading to bed. I'll update tomorrow, thank you

Comment: sorry i was not online,let me know if youare stuck

Comment: ok I put the right files in the right place, but the register template still isn't appearing. I'm getting one error: `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'NavbarController' is not a function, got undefined` I looked at the navbar controller code and it looks fine to me Also I'm not sure if that is actually causing the templates not to load

Comment: When I was installing the project I wasn't able to do the `npm install` command because I as getting this error: `chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command` I don't think that could be it could it?

Comment: Still haven't no, I'll try to post a fiddle within the hour.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if your angular is running by putting "alert" or "console" in your run section.

Then check your controller in the same way.
please provide a demo.

**OR:**

simply copy this working demo

```
    // create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

[angularJS starter](http://plnkr.co/edit/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg?p=preview)

provided by this tutorial.

[link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)

After all if you don't have to use AngularJS I recommend you to use angular (6 right now).

Comment: Okay I put a console method in my run section and the angular is running (ill update the post), I placed one in the router and it gave me an error, probably because I can't place one in the `when()` function. Which is good be cause the routing is being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ngRoute you have to have couple of things,

1. ng-view directive
2. routes
3. and a place to trigger your routes

You should have a main template let's say appController.html

```
<nav-bar>Your nav bar goes here</nav-bar>
<div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
```

And then you can have your routes in your app config

```
(function (angular) {
angular.module('DemoApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
   function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
       $routeProvider.
       when('/register', {
           templateUrl: 'register.html',
           controller: 'RegisterCtrl',
           controllerAs: 'vm'
       }).otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/'
       });
   }]).controller('RegisterCtrl', function () {
       var vm = this;
   });
})(window.angular);
```

And then in your navigation add an anchor tag to trigger the route,

```
<li><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
```

Learn more on ng-route in the documentation [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

Comment: Okay but why did the tutorial not use ng-view at all? And I disabled hash routing so I don't need that.

Comment: I updated my nav.html but it still doesnt work, is that right?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle of your current code so that I can help

Comment: Ok here's a fiddlehttps://jsfiddle.net/e5vtLrwy/10/ which files specifically? there's a lot, I just put the routing file there

Comment: ok nvm I DO have the `ng-view` class, it wasn't in the tutorial but it's in the boilerplate they have

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the reason that controller is registered with **"membership.authentication.controllers"** module while router is registered with **"membership.routing"** module.

Try registring router and controller with same module..

Comment: why would I do that? they're different modules, also the tutorial doesn't do that either